# How do I sum the length of a phone call associated from my call log table if it falls outside the clock in and clock out fields from another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to add the total time a person is called outside their time on shift in an Access DB. I'm trying to use an SQL query to do find the high, low, and average time a person is called. My tables are as follows:

People Table

```
ID  Last_Name   First_Name  Inactive    Home_Phone  Mobile_Phone    Person_ID
1   Doe         Jane        0           15558675309 13115552368     42
2   Smith       John        1           12135556162 14085550001     13
```

Call_log Table

```
ID  Direction   To          From        Date_Time               Result     
Length      
1   outbound    15558675309 15556346789 12/31/2018 4:28:00 PM   answered    0:03:54     
2   inbound     15556346789 14085550001 12/31/2018 4:28:00 PM   answered    0:04:23 
3   outbound    13115552368 15556346789 12/31/2018 4:15:00 PM   answered    0:01:13
```

Time_Entry Table

```
ID  Person_ID   Clock_In            Clock_Out   
1   42          01/01/2018 5:00 PM  01/01/2018 9:00 PM
2   42          01/01/2018 7:00 AM  01/01/2018 3:00 PM
3   13          01/01/2018 12:00 AM 01/01/2018 7:00 AM
```

I was thinking it might be something like:

```
    Select if Direction = "Outbound",
    from 
     call_log
    where Date_Time
      between Time_Entries.Clock_In and Time_Entries.Clock_Out
```

I'm looking for an output which contains all outbound calls to a person in the `People` Table including the `People.People_ID`, `People.First_Name`, `People.Last_Name`, `Call_Log.Date_Time`, and `Call_Log.length`

```
First_Name Last_Name Date_Time             Length 
Jane       Doe       12/31/2018 4:20:00 AM 00:25:00
```

There is a link between the `People_ID` fields in the `Time_Entries` table and the `People` table. I have also created a link between the `Mobile_Phone` and `Home_Phone` fields in the `People` table and the `To` and `From` fields in the `Call_Log` table

I after reading the comments I have changed things a little and am even further out of my swim lane.  I am very new at this and I apologize if this is an elementary question. I've been doing research and not getting very far.

Any help would be very helpful!

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and expected output - as text tables not images. You don't show GROUP BY clause in the SQL which is not a functional SQL anyway. Have you used the Access query designer? Try it to help build aggregate query. Put Direction in WHERE clause as additional filter criteria.

Comment: If Log has no relationship to People, how would you expect to get desired output?

Comment: As I said, I am quite new to this, I though the phone numbers being part of the record for each person with the People_ID in the People Table would make a relationship. I will create a relationship in the DB between inbound and outbound and the home_phone and mobile_phone fields. Thank you.

Comment: I will also add data and put in a mockup for what I'm trying to have as an output.

Comment: To and From are phone numbers? Do you want to assume person will always make/receive call from phones in their People record? I might be able to work with that.

Comment: The people in the people table are very well established and the outbound calls are all coming out of software system which includes informs which phone numbers are called.

Comment: What data types are Home_Phone, Mobile_Phone, To, From, Length fields? Are you actually saving Person_ID as foreign key, not ID, from People?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

Query1: LogUNION

```
SELECT ID, Direction, To As LogPhoneNum, Date_Time, Result, Length, "To" AS Src FROM Call_Log
UNION SELECT ID, Direction, [From], Date_Time, Result, Length, "From" FROM Call_Log;
```

Query2: PeopleUNION

```
SELECT ID, Last_Name, First_Name, Inactive, Home_Phone AS PeoplePhoneNum, "Home" AS Cat, Person_ID FROM People
UNION SELECT ID, Last_Name, First_Name, Inactive, Mobile_Phone, "Mobile", Person_ID FROM People;
```

Query3:

```
SELECT PeopleUNION.ID, PeopleUNION.Last_Name, PeopleUNION.First_Name, PeopleUNION.Inactive, PeopleUNION.PeoplePhoneNum, PeopleUNION.Cat, PeopleUNION.Person_ID, LogUNION.Direction, LogUNION.LogPhoneNum, LogUNION.Date_Time, LogUNION.Result, LogUNION.Length, LogUNION.Src
FROM LogUNION RIGHT JOIN PeopleUNION ON LogUNION.LogPhoneNum = PeopleUNION.PeoplePhoneNum;
```

That should get you to the output dataset shown in your question. Apply filter criteria as needed and use in subsequent queries.

Comment: June7, thank you so much! I'll give it a shot when I get home and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really worked and I'm looking at how to tell if the call was taken outside their shift, but I think I can go back and do that in excel. Thank you so much for all your help.